# TwinCAT HMI initialization does not work - missing screen

Tags: twincat, twincat-hmi

I am trying to get a hang of TwinCAT 3 HMI and have been looking at the tutorials on the net. For some reason, however, I can't even duplicate what is done in those. Right in the beginning, when creating the HMI project, the window in the tutorials looks like this:

[image: Working HMI project]

But when I try to replicate this on my PC, I get this:

[image: Failing HMI project]

I don't have the grey window with the BECKHOFF text, and I can't drag items from the toolbox to the GUI workspace. The project is stuck.

I don't understand what the problem here is and I couldn't find a reference to a similar problem. Is there a setting to create this by default, and/or a command to add a window to the workspace?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What version of VS are you using? I would assume that might be the cause for your problem:
`Min version VS2017 15.9 with ASP.NET`
`Min version VS2019 16.4`
`TC XAE shell (Should work, i created empty project and works fine)`

If you have correct version of the IDE I would suggest to reinstall the tool since it is probably an installation issue and should work out the box.

Comment: Also, if you rebuild solution, if there are any errors in the generated HTML code, it should give you the errors (sometimes the auto generated code from the designer could get scuffed, from my experience).

Comment: I am using the default editor installed by TC 4024.47 . Seems to be ASP .NET 2017, ver. 15.9.xxxxx

I think I will try to re-install TC and see what happens. I have been installing and uninstalling various Visual Studio products lately to test them. Maybe they have messed up something.

Comment: There is a difference between TC XAE shell and Visual Studio. Can you show is the entire window? I am not sure if I would go as far to install any packages to XAE shell since it is a stripped down version by Beckhoff. I my self prefer using Visual Studio 2019 and install TwinCAT there.

Comment: I am getting help from Beckhoff support now. It seems that TE2000 and the internal web browser doesn't install correctly on my machine, hence the problem.

Not sure yet what causes the problem, but it could be some PC safety restrictions imposed and installed by the organization I work for.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who happens to come across this problem, try the following steps:
First, close all open instances of XAE shell and visual studio 2019.
Next, assuming that TE2000 was already installed, run the TE2000 installer again. Select for "Repair".
Check for both XAE shell and VS2019 as options and run until completion.

Hopefully this resolves the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).